# Is it possible to use a router with dd-wrt/openWrt/etc as a radar detector?

Tags: openwrt, dd-wrt

Would it be possible to use a router with some kind of linux firmware and a laptop in a car as a radar detector?

Comment: Yes, with the right hardware. We can't help you find the right hardware here. We could help you make it work if you had driver troubles.

Comment: For that day when every car has a wifi connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For so many reasons. One obvious one:

- [802.11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11) = 2.4, 3.6, or 5 GHz

while:

- [X band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_band) = 8–12 GHz
- [Ku band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku_band) = 12–18 GHz
- [K band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_band) = 18–27 GHz
- [Ka band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka_band) = 26.5–40 GHz

Layman's explanation of the above: The router cannot “tune” to the needed frequencies.

(Then there's the DSSS vs burst detection, etc, etc, etc...)

Comment: yeah i figured it wouldn't be able to pick up the frequency, i just noticed somewhere that people talked about "radar detection" when discussing openwrt, it got my hopes up.  you know that'd be cool though!

Comment: Just to make it clear: those radars interfering with Wi-Fi are the [weather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_Doppler_Weather_Radar) and [military](https://wirednot.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/what-else-is-in-the-5-ghz-spectrum-hint-its-not-just-weather-radar/) ones.